Pid controller with encoder feedback for tank steering
I'm struggling to find a solution for my problem. I would like to write a simple PID controller in C/C++ that accepts a speed in RPM and controls the motors by receiving the feedback from the encoders.
I use optical encoders with 1024 pulses/revolution and DC motors.
I wasn't able to find any C/C++ examples and I can't figure out how to use the encoder data. What I get from encoders is the absolute counter for the ticks.
I also tried to use pid package from ROS, but I do not know how to add the encoders as feedback.

You can try any generic PID package. Your setpoint should be the target RPM and the feedback calculated from the encoder. Assuming you're updating the PID at some constant rate, keep track of number of counts from previous update. For instance you're running your PID loop at 5Hz, then count number of counts in 0.2seconds (1 / 5). Say X counts were counted in 0.2s, then the feedback will be 0.2*(x/1024)*60. Pass this as feedback to your PID.

Thank you a lot for your help. Can you please suggest me a pid package to try that work for sure? I tried some of them, but I wasnt able to make them work properly.

You can try the PID package in ROS control, I've had good success with it. (Although I have only worked with the ROS2 version of the package)

You need something that calculates the velocity from your position feedback, e.g. a derivative filter. A sidenote: your encoder will have an overflow of the position measurement, you should fix this depending of the bit-representation of your encoder.

Thank you! Is there any working example that I can study to better understand how to implement the PID? It is strange, but I wasn't able to find any C/C++ code that implements a PID for a speed control with encoders.

You can use this one here, but you have to calculate the velocity as already described.
